# Composition primaryKey JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Please Code of java class for the entity Detail_Consultation with Composite Primary Key

How to do it :

Patient (**Id**, Cin, Nom, Prenom, Date_Naiss, Adresse, Tel)
Consultation(**Num**, Date, #Id_Patient, Diagnostic)
Medicament(**Id**, Nom)
Detail_Consultation(**Num_Consultation**, **Id_Medicament**, Remarque)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Detail_Consultation` looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Detail_Consultation {
    @ManyToOne
    Consultation consultation;

    @ManyToOne
    Medicament medicament;

    String remarque;

    [...]
}
```

And your other entities use basic types for their PKs, then all you need to do is mark both relations as identity:

```
@Entity
class Detail_Consultation {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    Consultation consultation;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    Medicament medicament;

    String remarque;

    [...]
}
```

JPA uses the PK of the `Medicament` and `Consultation` to map the relation at database-level. As always with JPA, if you didn't use JPA's defaults, you'll have to adjust column names with `@JoinColums`/`@JoinColumn` and/or `@MapsId`.

More fancy setups are possible, i.e. if your compound identity has it's own entity you can use `@Embeddable` with `@EmbeddedId`. Entity Identity is covered in section 2.4 of the [JPA2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).